# Right click copy not working on C# application

Tags: c#

I've created a right click copy option on my datagrid but it doesn't seem to copy what is in the cell. Any reasons as to why this is the case? I've noticed that this happens when the user already has something in the clipboard.

```
    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            using (ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu())
            {
                MenuItem mItem = new MenuItem("Copy");
                m.MenuItems.Add(mItem);

                DataGridView.HitTestInfo information = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

                try
                {
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[information.RowIndex].Cells[information.ColumnIndex];
                    m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    mItem.Click += mItem_Click;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    void mItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: When the clipboard is clear everything is OK? Can you test if "dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()" is not null? You run this method in a different thread? If not, your main is in STA mode?

Comment: You shouldn't really catch general Exceptions like that. Is the `mItem_Click` raised properly?

Comment: @GrantWinney oh, you are right. But why you add the .Click event everytime the user cilck in a row, why not add it one time (maybe while datagrid is created) and go? The code could add more Click events for one row (maybe not a problem at all, but..)

Comment: @ChrisK - if by raising `mItem_Click` you mean does right clicking a cell produce a copy option then the answer is yes

Comment: By raising I meant if the eventhandler is actually called. Just set a breakpoint in it to find out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this won't work in your situation, but here's what I'd do (this looks like WinForms).

- Add a `ContextMenuStrip` to your form.
- Add a "Copy" menu item to the context menu and subscribe to the item's click event.
- Place the following code inside the click event *(Convert.ToString() returns an empty string if `.Value` is null, whereas .ToString() will throw an exception):*

  `Clipboard.SetText(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value));`
- Attach it to your `DataGridView` via the grid's `ContextMenuStrip` property.

To make this work for cells only, do a hit test to determine what portion of the grid is being clicked on, and then use the result to allow or cancel the context menu from opening.

```
private bool isCellClicked = false;

private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    isCellClicked = (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell);
}

private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !isCellClicked;
}
```